# align radio input-group-addon with a radio form-check in bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

i use a bootstrap 4 form with the bootstrap grid.
the user should add a temperature if present, otherwise the user should select the "N.A." radio button.

how can i align the two different elements properly.
i created that example:

https://jsfiddle.net/p7ewb94m/5/

```
<div class="container">
<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-form-label col-6" for="">Temperature</label>

    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <input type="radio" name="gridRadios">
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-addon">°C</span>
      </div>

       <div class="form-check">
         <label class="form-check-label">
           <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios1" value="option1" checked>
           N.A.
         </label>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to align elements properly in row,Have a look at this might help you

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  

     <form class="form-inline" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-form-label" for="">Temperature</label>
      &nbsp; &nbsp
      </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <input type="radio" name="gridRadios">
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-addon">°C</span>
          </div>
    </div>
  &nbsp; &nbsp
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="radio">
        <label class="radio-inline control-label">
          <input type="radio" id="amount_25" name="amount" value="25" checked="">
          N.A
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
   
    </form>
```

expand snippet(full page) to see on large display

Comment: this is a simple fix. but is there not other way, a bootstrap-way? btw. the css fix should be `.fixme { padding-left: 0.8125rem; }`

Comment: You mean alignments @juke?

Comment: your code above does not solve my question somehow. you have a inline form `form-inline`. i created a jsfiddle with your code https://jsfiddle.net/p7ewb94m/6/ .

Comment: check this fiddle i have removed form-inline, but then to align radio button properly we need to give padding when it is vertical https://jsfiddle.net/girish28892/p7ewb94m/9/

Comment: this is not helpfull! the radio buttons are not vertical aligned! and i am using bootstrap 4 !